# How can I match all elements that start with a number or a relevant symbol in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Here's my "where" part:

```
$fornecedor->where = "nome_fantasia REGEXP '^[0-9+#-]*$%'";
```

It does not work. How can I match it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REGEXP` doesn't want `%` at the end. Also, your pattern searches the entire string because it starts with `^` and ends with `$`. Try this:

```
$fornecedor->where = "nome_fantasia REGEXP '^[0-9+#-]'";
```

This searches only for a single matching character at the beginning of the line, since you don't care about anything after that.

Comment: Doesn't the `-` need escaped (twice)?

Comment: No, when it's the first or last character in a class the `-` is not treated specially.